# Accessing MuleSoft Anypoint Exchange Properties

Tags: mule, mulesoft, anypoint-studio, aws-secrets-manager, mule-connector

I am using [Amazon Secrets Manager Properties Provider Connector](https://docs.mulesoft.com/amazon-secrets-manager-properties-provider-connector/latest/) in an attempt to connect to AWS Secrets Manager from my anypoint application. The documentation makes it seem like I can configure the input properties(regions/secretkey/secret) and then the connector will run on application startup, and retrieve the secrets. Is this a correct understanding, and if so, how can I access/debug the properties/secrets once they are loaded? If this is not the correct understanding, what additional step do I have to take to retrieve the secrets?

Thanks!

Current I have the connector set up as a Configuration in the global.xml of the project. When running the app, I am trying to debug it out by doing something like p('name_of_secret').

Comment: Share the connector configuration and how do you set the properties, masking confidential information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Accessing secrets using MuleSoft's Amazon Secrets Manager Properties Provider in an depends on how you set the secrets in AWS and where you are using them in the application. The later is similar to how other properties are used in Mule 4.

- If you are accessing the secret to configure a connector you should use the placeholder syntax and the prefix `aws-secrets`. Example: `<s3:connection accessKey="${aws-secrets::accessKey}" ...` .
- If you are accessing the secret in a DataWeave expression you use the p() function. Example: `#[p("aws-secrets::accessKey")]`.

See the [documentation for other examples](https://docs.mulesoft.com/amazon-secrets-manager-properties-provider-connector/latest/amazon-secrets-manager-examples).